# Simple Navbar in Jquery Mobile not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-navbar

I'm trying to do a simple jquery mobile navbar like the one shown here:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/tabs/#&ui-state=dialog

The problem I'm having is that when I link to an html file, it loads without any styling or "jquery mobileness".  Here are my snippets

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="homePage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
            <div data-role="navbar" >
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="maps.html" data-ajax="false">Map</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="events">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="b">
                        <li data-role="list-divider">1</li>
                        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                        <li data-role="staclist-divider">2</li>
                        <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

maps.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
                <li data-role="list-divider">1</li>
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                <li data-role="list-divider">2</li>
                <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The #events id loads just fine.  I'm expecting the content of maps.html (which is identical to the #events div) to load.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how jquery mobile works, but the demo makes it look like what I'm doing is possible.  Instead, I'm just getting something like this

[image: unstyled]

When I'm expecting this:

[image: styled]

I know I could just throw it all onto one page, but I'm really hoping not to.  I'm also hoping not to repeat the header on every page.  This seemed like a decent solution, but I feel like I might not be using the tools properly.  I've tried googling and have found other examps, but I am not sure why mine isn't working.

Comment: Why do you have the `data-ajax` flag set to false for the map page?

Comment: I've tried both.  There's no difference.  The example I copied from the jquery mobile site has it, so I put it.

Comment: maps.html is missing the page, header and navbar divs. Try adding these.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.  Adding those just makes everything disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think your maps.html should look like this:

```
<div class="tablist-content" data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
        <li data-role="list-divider">1</li>
        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">2</li>
        <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

No need to put the standard HTML header.